# Installing libtorrent for Python 3.6 on Windows 7

Tags: python, libtorrent

**Windows 7 x64 - Python 3.6**

I am trying to install the libtorrent Python library in windows using the instructions [here](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/master/docs/python_binding.rst#building-using-setup-py).

After navigating to the setup.py file, I used the following commands

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

In the cmd window, I get the following messages:

```
C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\libtorrent-master>python setup.py build
running build

C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\libtorrent-master>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-pac
kages\python_libtorrent-1.2.0-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-pack
ages\python_libtorrent-1.2.0-py3.6.egg-info
```

What else do I need to do? Because trying to import the libtorrent library, the interpreter comes up with this message:

```
>>> import libtorrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
File , line 1, in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'
```

No matter what, the proper DLL is not available in the Python folder and thus I can't import the library.

Using the MSI installer from the Sourceforge link doesn't help either since it's severely outdated.

Comment: You can install it with `pip` using [this wheel](http://stamkaly.pythonanywhere.com/python_libtorrent-1.2.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl) if you are on 64-bit Python or [this](http://stamkaly.pythonanywhere.com/python_libtorrent-1.2.0-py3-none-win32.whl) for 32. Just till I write a full answer...

Answer (score 3):

If you took a quick look at the `setup.py` file you are trying to install, you would [see](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/master/bindings/python/setup.py#L96) that it assumes you have installed the [`boost C++ libraries`](http://www.boost.org/) in order to generate the `libtorrent.pyd` required for Python. You would expect to get an error, but that's not how things are right now.

---

### Installing `libtorrent` for Python without building it

For your own convenience, I have built Python Wheels of `libtorrent` which can be installed with `pip install`. Please take into consideration, that if it does not work, it means you will have to build your own `.pyd` for your machine.

- [Wheel for Python 3.5
  32-bit](http://stamkaly.pythonanywhere.com/python_libtorrent-1.2.0-py3-none-win32.whl)
- [Wheel for Python 3.5
  64-bit](http://stamkaly.pythonanywhere.com/python_libtorrent-1.2.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl)

---

### Building and installing `libtorrent` for Python on Windows 7

In order to get `boost` working, you will first have to download and install:

1. [Windows 7 SDK and .NET Framework
   4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)
2. [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Build
   Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)

After you are done installing those, you will have to add their directories to your `PATH`:

1. Right-Click `Computer` and go to `Properties`:

   [image: Right-Click <code>Computer</code> and go to <code>Properties</code>]
2. Click `Advanced System Settings` at the left:

   [image: Advanced System Settings]
3. Click `Environment Variables` at the bottom-right:

   [image: Environment Variables]
4. Choose `PATH` from the top list and click `Edit...`:

   [image: PATH]
5. Inside the box that popped up add these if you want to be building
   for 32-bit Python:

   ```
   ;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\
   ```

   Or these for 64-bit:

   ```
   ;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\
   ```
6. Click `OK` both from the pop up and from the `Environment Variables`
   window, and leave the other one opened, we will need it later on..

Now everything is set up and you are ready to install the [`boost C++ libraries`](http://www.boost.org/). Because `libtorrent`'s Python bindings have some [issues](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/2259) with boost versions higher than `1.63` (in August 2017), make sure to download [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.63.0/boost_1_63_0.zip).
After you have downloaded it:

1. Extract it
2. Open a `Command Prompt` and `cd` into the extracted directory
3. Run `bootstrap.bat` to install the libraries

After that is done, go to the `System Properties` window you left open from earlier, and click `Environment Variables` again.
Click on `New...` and add these:

```
Variable name: BOOST_ROOT
Variable value: "<full path to extracted directory of boost>"
```

and click `OK` to both windows again.

There is one last step before you can actually start building `libtorrent`, and that is specifying your Python version into a configuration file.

1. Open a **new** `Command Prompt`
2. Execute 
   `echo using python : <Python Version> : "<Python Path>" : "<Python Path>\Include" : "<Python Path>\libs" ; >> user-config.jam`

   For example:
   `echo using python : 3.5 : "C:\Program Files\Python35" : "C:\Program Files\Python35\Include" : "C:\Program Files\Python35\libs" ; >> user-config.jam`

Now to build `libtorrent`:

1. [Download](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/archive/master.zip)
   and extract the [repository](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent)
2. Open `<libtorrent extracted directory>\include\libtorrent\session.hpp` in a notepad, find the line that starts with `std::snprintf`, remove `std::` and save.
3. In a `Command Prompt`, `cd` into `<libtorrent extracted
   directory>\bindings\python`
4. Now

   if you are building for 32-bit Python execute:

   `bjam libtorrent-link=static boost-link=static stage_module`

   or

   `bjam libtorrent-link=static boost-link=static address-model=64 stage_module` for 64-bit
5. Just be patient, when it finishes you will have a `libtorrent.pyd`
   in `<libtorrent extracted directory>\bindings\python` which you can
   import inside Python!

Comment: Which windows SDK do i need for windows 10? I am trying to follow your answer, but it seems like for windows 10, the SDK is different?

Comment: I remember struggling to make this work for windows 10, the files of the SDK seemed to be different. Could you tell me in which step you are? I will take a look at it again

Comment: Hey @Stam Kaly, thanks for replying! I'm at step 1 actually. I couldnt find the equivalent of `Windows 7 SDK and .NET Framework 4`. Then it leads to issues with `step 5` when i'm trying to add it to `path`. Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: [This](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) is where you should get the SDK from. The paths will be different so don't move on to the next step.

Comment: Okay thanks for it! let me try it out and see if I can figure out how to do it. If it doesn't work, perhaps I could open a question thread and maybe if you have the time, you could help guide me along? (:

Comment: Sure, I could help you with any problems you face!

Comment: Because I don't have windows anymore, my answer won't help you much, but I have some things in mind that could help. Check if this folder exists: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0" and e-mail me at stamkaly@gmail.com we'll talk about it from there and once I have enough info I will give you a full answer!