# Difference between Visual Studio, Build Tools and Windows SDK

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

As far as I get it Visual Studio includes both and the SDK allows writings apps for Windows, I tried online but I haven't found any clear comparison.
Any help would be great.

EDIT: For instance you could build cross platform apps using Xamarin in VS, is it possible using build tools?
I tried to use [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478842/installing-libtorrent-for-python-3-6-on-windows-7) to build libtorrent, but it didn't work until I installed VS, I tried to take the tutorial step by step, at many points I got errors about files not found.

So (if I understand correctly) the SDK is a library to build Windows programs, but aside from the IDE, what sets build tools apart from VS?

Sorry but English is not my first language.

Comment: You asked a question that cannot be answered. Though @SurvialMachine gave an answer below, we can see it might not show "clear comparison" part that you might want. I guess you might be more interested in the "relationship" among them, not just "difference", but that needs to be asked in a more specific way.

Comment: “it didn't work until I installed VS” lacks of clarity. The installer of Build Tools does offer you options to install both VC++ compilers/MSBuild/Windows 10 SDK, but you didn't mention what components you chose to install, and more importantly, the actual build errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visual Studio is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). It's the user interface.

Build Tools include the compiler that compiles your source code into machine code.

Windows SDK contains headers, libraries and sample code used to develop applications.

Comment: BTW, since VS2017, Build Tools is more like a special Visual Studio edition, as it can be installed side by side.

Comment: @LexLi do we need both? What's gonna happen if we don't have build tools?

Comment: For simple understanding --
Build tools help to compile the source code.
Before VS2017 Build Tools came up with VS itself.
After VS2017 Build Tools came up as separate build package. We can install this build tools when VS IDE is not installed.

Comment: @AHAMEDAAQIB a simple "yes" or "no" to cikatomo's question would be sufficed.  I'll ask it again. IF we have VS Studio Installed, on the SAME machine in the same environment do we NEED to have VS Build Tools.  I'd hate to have to install stuff TWICE on the same memory.  Already have issues with trying to have file space.

Comment: @Benjamin to answer your question 'No'. If you have VS installed you don't need to install VS Build tools separately (By default If you have Visual Studio, then you already have Build Tools installed.). VS Build Tools allow you to build Visual Studio projects from a command-line interface. So, when you don't want to install VS you can use VS build tools to build native and managed MS Build-based applications but  you need a valid Visual Studio license (community, professional or enterprise).

Answer (score 22):

To add more details to describe the relationship between VS, Build Tools and Windows SDK.

1.The full name of `Build Tools` is `Build Tools for VS`. Normally we call it [msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019). It's the build system of VS IDE, VS IDE calls `msbuild` to build managed projects. (If we install VS IDE, no matter which workload we choose, msbuild will be enabled by default)

2.Since VS2017, MSbuild becomes a separate build package. It means we can choose to install this package to build projects in remote server where VS IDE is not installed. So for us who use VS2017 and higher, msbuild is a `default tool` installed by IDE used to manage and build projects.

So we can also choose to install the tool separately, we can find the `Build Tools for VS2019`(stand-alone build package) in [Tools for VS](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) part. AFAIK, msbuild can build most of the managed projects like what we do in VS IDE.

**For example**, if we're developing **asp.net core** web projects in VS, we need to install this workload:

[image]

And if we need to build it in remote server without VS, we need to install these two workloads in Build Tools Package:

[image]

[image]

So for most managed projects, we only need to make sure we've installed corresponding workloads and components, then we can build them in command-line with Build Tools package.

3.As for Windows SDK, it contains the headers, libraries, metadata, and tools for developing and building Windows 10 apps. If you're trying to build UWP projects, then you need to install corresponding windows sdk in VS IDE(develop and build) or in Build Tools Package(only for build).

**In addition:** To build Xamarin cross-platform projects with single Build Tools package, I think you should install both `Mobile Development with .Net` and `.net core build Tools` workloads.

Comment: So what is the relation to `Windows SDK`? If I want to be able to compile C++ code without having Visual Studio installed, will I need *both* `Windows SDK` *and* `Build Tools for VS`, or just one of these 2?